# Redireccion entre páginas en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Buen dia comunidad

Tengo una pregunta. Soy nuevo en Laravel. ¿como hago para navegar entre páginas?. Es decir, tengo una pagina de inicio y un menú con una opción para ir a otra pagina que tiene un formulario, ¿que debo incluir en el href para que se vaya a esa pagina que tiene el formulario?. He intentado con la función redirect o route pero me sale error.

Agradezco su respuesta

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: Ya revisaste la documentación?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para navegar puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera supongamos que tenemos este código
, un simpe menú en el cual deseas que te lleve a diferentes lugares tu de proyecto.

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <span class="dropdown-item-text">Dropdown item text</span>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Inicio</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Trabajos</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Quien soy</a>
</div>
```

Para ello, tenemos el método `routes()`, el cual uso. y con el podemos decirle a laravel a donde ir. Y ese menú quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <span class="dropdown-item-text">Dropdown item text</span>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('inicio') }}">Inicio</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('trabajo') }}">Trabajos</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('acercaDe') }}">Quien soy</a>
</div>
```

Sin embargo, esto no acaba ahí, debes especificarle a Laravel lo que pusiste en `route()`, para ello, abres tu archivo `web.php` y ahí agregas las rutas... En este caso, seria algo así:

```
Route::get('/inicio', function(){
  return view('inicio');
});

Route::get('/trabajo', function(){
  return view('trabajo');
});

Route::get('/acercaDe', function(){
  return view('acercaDe');
});
```

Y de esta manera puedes hacer redirecciones a tus vistas. Para profundizar mas lo que te puse, te agrego la [Doc. de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x)

Comment: @Edgar_Gc muchas gracias por la respuesta. Tuve que hacer algo adicional pero  me fue de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Yo hago lo que te propone Edgar Gc pero con el nombre de las rutas.
Es decir, el enlace lo puedo tener así:

```
<a href="{{route('registro_visitantes')}}">Registro de Visitantes</a>
```

Y la ruta en web.php la tengo así:

```
Route::get('/visitantes', [App\Http\Controllers\RegistroVisitantesController::class, 'registro_visitantes'])->name('registro_visitantes');
```

Y aludo al name.

Tengo también un controlador con ese método en cuestión:

```
public function registro_visitantes(){
        return view('registro_visitantes');
    }
```